# Is my understanding of writing a pseudo code(java) correct?

Tags: java, pseudocode

So I just learnt how to write pseudo codes and so lets say this is my code

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
class Watever{
public static final String foo="12345151";
public static String today;
public static String expiry;
public static void date(){
    SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    Calendar calen = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date todayDate = calen.getTime();
    today = DATE_FORMAT.format(todayDate);
    calen.add(Calendar.MONTH, 4);
    Date expirationDate = calen.getTime();
    expiry = DATE_FORMAT.format(expirationDate);
    }

public static void main(String[] args){
    date();
    System.out.println(today);
    int bar = Integer.parseInt(foo);
    System.out.println(bar);
    }
      }
```

Would this be an acceptable pseudo code(given that we're gonna write the code in java)

```
PROGRAM Watever:
  Declare public final String foo="12345151";
  Declare public String today;
  method date():
             GET Today's date;
             today= Today's date;
             expiry= today+ 4 MONTHS;
             Format today AND expiry to "dd/MM/yy"
  method main(String[] args):
             CALL date();
             PRINT today;
             Convert String foo to int bar;
             PRINT bar;
END
```

and lets say if we use scanner object to for system.in, do we have to say that we used it or do we just use

```
 PROMPT user "Enter number: ";
 GET num;
```

also how do we write the pseudocode for a printf(formatted string)

Comment: This depends on how "pseudo" do you want to go, e.g. the acceptable-ness of the pseudo code changes based on whether you want to tailor the algorithm to be understandable by non-tech savvy people or for programmers that already know the basic concepts just to explain the code flow to them.

Comment: @CeilingGecko This is for my assignment, my lecturer's going to read it, but would my example be acceptable? my problem is that I don't understand if we need to like say we used the Date class and SimpleDateFormat or just write like I did

Comment: pseudo code is abstraction, it is used to describe how algorithm should work, not how it it will be implement in some language. so you cant have pseudocode for printf as it might not exist in other languages

Comment: @Kazem if ill be your lecturer, i wouldnt accept your example, go try to find some algorithm, even for solving quadratic equation and  explain whole process step by step using pseudo code. and forget about java, your task is to write this in this way, so guy who does not know any java and has to implement it in ie python

Comment: @user902383 Haven't I explained the steps involving for example getting today's date and expiry date in a way that any1 who reads it could understand it? Which parts of my pseudo code are limited only to people with knowledge about java?

Comment: @Kazem you didnt, bit about limiting to java was to part of your question about printf. your pseudocode in principle is good, is showing how it can be used to replace code, but in my opinion if you used it to show  how some algorithm works not some random code it will look better

Comment: @user902383 Oh I see, that was just a question cuz I wasn't sure if we're supposed to use printf or just print since only few languages use printf and I can't provide my actual program code since I'm worried it might get tagged for plagiarism later.. lol but thanks  will try my best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudocode is a more informal expression. 
It is language independent. 
You do not have to declare variables in pseudocode.
You just have to get the message across in a good manner.

For printf you can use  `print "message"`

Hi, you can check out the following links they will definitely help.

[link 1](http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~jdalbey/SWE/pdl_std.html)

[link 2](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/P/pseudocode.html)

[link 3](http://www.unf.edu/~broggio/cop2221/2221pseu.htm)

Comment: Thanks for those links, and so would what I wrote be considered wrong? If I present it as a pseudo code for my code above?

Comment: Your code above might be considered correct, depending on your teacher's requirements. I cannot tell for sure.

Comment: I see, the reason I followed that format was cuz it was similar to what the lecturer showed us during the lecture. I have 1 more question, a part of my program requires me to find substring of a String from lets say the index of 7th occurence of "," to the 8th occurence of "," so I have created my own method to be able to find the nth occurence, because indexof is only limited to the first and last. Do I need to state the nth occurence method that I used or is something like this fine?
String StudentID = Line substring from 1st index of "," to 2nd index of ","; AND replace all "," with "";

Comment: You can write it like this:
Find StudentId string between given comma index;
Clear StudentId string of commas;

Answer (score 1):

If someone asks for pseudo-code, that normally means, a fast sketched, outlined algorithm. Of course still carefully crafted. One considers what is really meant, and comes to a choice of steps and data structures. See [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71276/checking-that-all-occurrences-of-g-have-another-g-as-a-neighbor/71510#71510) for how a fuzzy requirement can be refined and put in code.

Pseudo-code normally looks a bit nicer than what you tried. So

- Be consistent with respect to style: if using capitals (or bold) for reserved words, then do it everywhere.
- Identifiers with spaces are okay, but (from my Algol68 experience) I would rather have them all small letters and no quotes.
- Function calls, separate parameters, are best read when the separation is clear, with parentheses and commas.

So:

```
PROGRAM Whatever:
    CONSTANT String foo = "12345151";
    FIELD String today;

    METHOD date ():
         today := LIBRARY todays date();
         expiry := today + 4 MONTHS;
         today := date format(today, expiry, "dd/MM/yy").

    BEGIN
         date();
         PRINT(today);
         bar := convert string to int(foo);
         PRINT(bar);
    END
```

About "Convert String foo to int bar": that is a top-down refinement style, also possible. It declares the intention of a piece of code and with that nicely documents the code.

```
whatever:
    String foo;
    ...
    convert string foo to integer bar;
    ...
    ... .

convert string foo to integer bar:
    int bar = atoi(foo).
```

Last but not least, about the content, the pseudo-algorithm itself. In your case you are in effect only calling `date` without parameters and result, and that does a read and as side-effect stores something calculated in a field `today`. A *function* without side-effect night be more useful. A better name certainly.

Answer (score 0):

Psuedo code doesn't have to be that detailled, if you and other people can understand what it should do, then it's good enough.